# Is this Arrowhead vine healthy?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, vines

This is my second arrowhead vine plant. The plant is still in the same pot it came from nursery. I will be soon re-potting it in a ceramic pot.

But the plant is very droopy and looks like it is sad. The bottom three leaves have turned yellow. I water it only when the topsoil goes dry to the touch. And it is getting good indirect light. When I other arrowhead vines, they are very bushy and green. Mine looks kinda less green and droopy with all the leaves diverging and not forming a bush like other vines.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It just needs a bigger pot so its got more root room....

Comment: @Bamboo I placed it in a bugger pot, and nothing seems to have changed. The lower ones are still dangling low.

Answer (score 1):

Change one of the following, --- give it more light.  It looks pale from lack of light.  Plants that are getting the right amount of light stand up taller. --- The roots are not getting enough oxygen. -The soil is either too dense or -the plant is root bound.   If the soil is too dense them take it out of the pot, wash off the roots add drainage to the soil in the pot, like perlite.   If the plant is root bound repot it in a larger pot about 6cm (2") larger, first wash off the soil that is on the roots and loosen the roots up so that can spread more evenly in the pot.  Use a potting soil with about 30% drainage matter, like perlite or pumice.

Comment: The soil is not dense, it is fluffy. I gave it very bight indirect light and added pumice; The plant is still droopy.